# what does the expression "my five cents" mean?

Tags: idioms

I saw this in an informal email but I don't understand it.

Can you help me with the meaning and the context in which it is used (if used at all or if it simply a mistake from the sender)

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like a variant of [_my two cents_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents), which would have been much easier to find in a search. It's hard to tell if the writer was trying to be amusing by changing _two_ to _five_, or if the idiom was simply mistyped.

Comment: If you want an expert to explain the meaning in the context, you might start by *showing the phrase in context*.

Comment: J.R. I have also seen 'my five cents'. It is just a variant.  Perhaps this form is more common in non-english speaking countries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more famous expression is *my two cents*. But I guess with the decreasing value of money through inflation, time has had its say for the added 3 cents. ;) Another reason for this relatively new variant might be the fact that in earlier times the next larger denomination  coin after 1 cent was a [2 cent coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-cent_piece_%28United_States_coin%29), but these days, the next larger coin after a penny is 5 cents (the word *nickel* came into common use more recently). Just a thought, though![image]

Have a look at [this wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents), which tells us that the expression primarily means throwing in our own advice, valued at 2 or 5 cents. The UK version has *pence* or *penn'orth* instead of cents (for obvious reasons). Here is an entry at the [EnglishEnhancer with some good examples](http://www.englishenhancer.com/2008/09/03/my-five-cents/).
 And there is another [question right here at English.StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32912/where-did-the-expression-my-two-cents-come-from) which talks about the etymology of this phrase.

And a little Google is always a good learning habit.